# Way to speed up python code with numba? Includes multiple functions and two nested loops

Tags: python, loops, numpy, numba

I'm working on a program which basically preforms an N-body simulation, but with multiple potentials and soon to be time-dependant potential. Currently the program is insanely slow, whilst my supervisors code is 600 times quicker, though that is expected - it's written in C.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linalg as la
from scipy import interpolate as ir


G=0.004300913551233961 #Grav. constant
Mh=8.*10**11 #Mass of halo
ah,ch=16.*10**3,15.3 #Halo paramters
c=1/(np.log(1.+ch)-ch/(1.+ch)) #Simplification for formula
Mb=5*10**9 #Mass of bulge
ab=500 #Bulge parameter
Md=6.8*10**10 #Mass of disk
ad,bd=3000,280 #Disk parameters
Mp=2.*10**4 #Progenitor mass
ap=15. #Progenitor parameter

xs1=np.zeros((5000,3)) #Stellar coordinates
vs1=np.zeros((5000,3)) #Stellar velocities
v2=np.zeros(3) #Stellar velocities at half-step

pd=np.load('test.npy') #Loading progenitor data
tp=pd[:,6] #Assigning time-steps of progentior
x,y,z=pd[:,0],pd[:,1],pd[:,2] #Assigning coordinates
vx,vy,vz=pd[:,3],pd[:,4],pd[:,5] #Assigning velocities
f,a=pd[:,-2],pd[:,-1] #Lagrange points
f1,f2,f3=ir.interp1d(tp,x),ir.interp1d(tp,y),ir.interp1d(tp,z) #Interp1d func-s
g1,g2,g3=ir.interp1d(tp,vx),ir.interp1d(tp,vy),ir.interp1d(tp,vz) #Interp1d func-s
h1,h2=ir.interp1d(tp,f),ir.interp1d(tp,a)
xs,vs=np.array([0,0,0]),np.array([0,0,0])

h=np.zeros((10,3)) #Empty arrays
#Norms for stars
def md():
    md=la.norm(xs)
    return md

#Norms between star and progenitor
def nd():
    nd=la.norm(xs-[f1(t),f2(t),f3(t)])
    return nd

#Norm of projenitor
def nm():
    nm=la.norm([f1(t),f2(t),f3(t)])
    return nm

#Progenitor force
def pfc():
    pfc=np.multiply(-G*Mp*(nd()**2+ap**2)**(-1.5),(xs-[f1(t),f2(t),f3(t)]),out=h[1])
    return pfc

#Halo force
def hfc():
    hfc=np.multiply(-G*Mh*c*(np.log(1+md()/ah)/md()**3-1/(md()**2*(ah+md()))),xs,out=h[2])
    return hfc

#Bulge force
def bfc():
    bfc=np.multiply(-G*Mb/(md()*(ab+md())**2),xs,out=h[4])
    return bfc

#Disk force
def dfc():
    q=np.multiply(xs,[1.,1.,(1+ad/(bd**2+xs[2]**2)**0.5)],out=h[0])
    dfc=np.multiply(-G*Md/(xs[0]**2+xs[1]**2+(ad+(bd**2+xs[2]**2)**0.5)**2)**1.5,q,out=h[5])
    return dfc

#Dynamic timestep
def ddt():
    for j in range(w):
        xs=xs1[j]
        ddt.append(min(((nd()/abs(la.norm(pfc())))**0.5/10.,(md()/abs(la.norm(dfc()+hfc()+bfc())))**0.5))/10.)
    ddt=min(ddt)

t,w=.5,1
xs1[0]=[f1(t),f2(t),f3(t)]*h2(t)
vs1[0]=np.random.normal([g1(t),g2(t),g3(t)],1)
for t in range(0,10000,5):
    for i in range(w):
        xs=xs1[i]
        vs=vs1[i]
        v2=vs+(dfc()+bfc()+hfc()+pfc())*dt/2
        xs=xs+v2*dt
        vs=v2+(dfc()+bfc()+hfc()+pfc())*dt/2
        xs1[i]=xs
        vs1[i]=vs

    if t>10*w+5:
        xs1[w]=[f1(t),f2(t),f3(t)]*h2(t)
        vs1[w]=np.random.normal([g1(t),g2(t),g3(t)],1)
        xs1[w+1]=[f1(t),f2(t),f3(t)]*h1(t)
        vs1[w+1]=np.random.normal([g1(t),g2(t),g3(t)],1)
        w+=2
```

As you can see there are a lot of operation going on each loop. I've tried making a program which calculates the orbit for each star separately, as they are considered non-interacting with one another. The problem arises there, as I'm using a dynamic timestep, so the probability of every star being modelled until t=10000 is very low and they resulting image is inaccurate.

I searched for some kind of solution and it seems that **numba** is the one that perfectly fits this problem as it uses C (from what I gathered) to do all the calculations, but there is not enough info about how to use it for my specific problem.

I would've started writing in C, but again I don't have the time to start learning this as my project needs to keep moving. I've decided to post here, only because I've tried everything that I could and I really need some direction.

My program is very slow and I'm sure that when I add the time-dependant potential - it might screech to a halt. So if there's any sensible way to speed my code, I'de love to hear it and I'd be very grateful.

Edit: I should add, that I feel the other program, where I model each star separately, has the added bonus of not needing to create a huge numpy array to store coordinates. Unfortunately the problem with the timestep still stays.

Comment: The strategy for numba is simple: Take python functions, ensure there are no calls to functions not supported in `nopython` mode and then apply the `nb.jit(nopython=True)` decorator to that function. Often times it's better to unroll vectorized numpy operations, but sometimes not depending on the exact situation. Use `timeit` to test functions of the application to be sure.

Comment: But first I would use a combination of `cProfile` and `line_profiler` to figure out why your code is slow in the first place.

Comment: @JoshAdel Thank you! Where can I find the list of functions supported by nopython?

Comment: The documentation is a good place to start: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html and http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html

Comment: @JoshAdel Perfect! What do you personally think when looking at my code as a whole - is it possible to make it quicker with numba, or is it too cluttered?

Also, is numba only applicable to function calls or can it be used on loops?

Comment: I think you could see a large benefit from numba, but a few things: (1) pass variables to functions rather than using globals, (2) something looks strange in the `ddt` function with the `append`. You apply numba to a full function and it's going to compile all of the code in the function. It helps with small functions and functions with lots of looping.

Comment: @JoshAdel I changed everything I could, it is faster now, but I feel that the scipy interpolation is slow, but it's not allowed by numba, so I have to keep it as it is. Is there any way to interpolate using numba? I need simple 1D interpolation for (x,t),(y,t),(z,t) etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135208/discussion-between-joshadel-and-tigs).